# Importing a python module after execute a command on python

Tags: python, import, module, console, command

I work on python and I want to import a module just after execute a command with python in the same script. I need to execute the command before importing the module.

When I start to execute my command on a console, then I can open python and `import MyModule` but if I pass my command by python then `import MyModule` report in console :

> ImportError: No module named MyModule

I already try this two methods :

- `subprocess.call()`
  [image]
- `os.system()`
  [image: m]

Any Idea ?

Comment: I think that the MyModule directory is not in the same directory as your program.

Comment: Please don't share screenshots of code. You can include code as [formatted text](/help/formatting) -- Paste your code into the editor and add three backticks ( ``` ) on the lines before and after your code block.

Answer (score 1):

What I usually do and what I usually see other programmers do is that they import their libraries first, before they even put any line of code. This is also helpful to see what libraries you're working with since the beginning of the code.

```
import subprocess
import Mymodule

script = "command"
subprocess.call = (script, shell = True)
```

Please let me know if this fix the issue, here's also a cool [article](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/modules-in-python) that might help you.